# Can a primary key default be NULL? Why is it described as such?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, primary-key

I have a table that when I `describe` it is:

```
mysql> DESC my_table;  
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |  
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
| contact_id | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |  
| location   | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |  
| city       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |  
| state      | varchar(2)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |  
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

My question is: why for the primary key `contact_id` the `Default` is displayed as `NULL`?
I created the table with `NOT NULL` for the column and the `Primary Key` can not be `NULL` anyway.
How can `Null` be `NO` and `Default` be `NULL`?

Comment: `NULL` is always the default if nothing else was defined.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:I defined `NOT NULL` on creation. Not sure what you mean

Comment: The `NULL` there means _there is no default_ rather than the default is `NULL`. So if no `contact_id` is specified mysql will check for the default value, that is `NULL`, then it will throw an error as `contact_id` cannot be `NULL`.

Comment: @bmorris591:So what is the difference with the lines that have `Null`=`YES`? Seems useless/non-sensical information to me

Comment: What it means is if you try to create a row without specifying this column, you'll get an error because the NULL default is not valid (actually, that won't happen for this table, because it's also set to `auto_increment`). What else should it display in the Default column if you haven't specified a default?

Answer (score 5):

The fact that it can't be null makes the content of the 'default' column irrelevant. They are using 'null' in the 'default' column because otherwise they would need another magic value to indicate 'irrelevant', 'unused', end.

Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 4):

`NOT NULL` in MySQL is used to indicate that the field can not be empty. In your case the Primary Key field `contact_id` is correctly shown as No in the attribute `Null`. `Default` clause in a data type specification indicates a default value for a column. Here your Primary Key Field `contact_id` does not have any default value. So it is shown as `NULL`.

Comment: So it can not "understand" that `NULL` can not be a default value for the specific column since it is defined as `PRIMARY KEY`?

Answer (score 0):

Rest assured that even if the default column show a `(NULL)` value for the primary key field, it won't matter. Lets list every cases when Default has this (NULL) value :

- if your SQL request provides a value to the primary field : Default is not called
- if your SQL request doesnt provide a value but is an autoincrement field : Defaut is not called
- if your SQL request doesnt provide a value and the field is not an autoincrement and can be null : Default is called and NULL is inserted
- if your SQL request doesnt provide a value and the field is not an autoincrement **and can NOT be null** : Default is called but you get an error telling you that this field "cannot be null"

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, NULL in the default column indicates that the user didn't specify any value as the default value.