# mysql "Default" column value NULL is getting erased, on executing alter table for PRIMARY KEY

Tags: mysql, linux, primary-key, alter-table

I have a fresh new table created in Mysql database.
I added a new field, called "rks" with Default NULL, datatype varchar(20).

If i execute alter table, to modify this field, i can see that the "NULL" in Default column is getting erased to blank (in case it is a primary key), however if in case i degrade it from primary key, doing an alter on this variable, retains the state "NULL".

Please note: I use "default null" while using alter table as below.

```
mysql> alter table FileTable modify column rks varchar(40) default NULL collate latin1_bin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**Further observation:**

1. In case field is primary key, and of type varchar, doing alter
   table removes NULL.
2. In case field is type bigint, and primary
   key, the NULL is changed to 0 after alter table.

I wish to know, why this change happens?

```
Newly created:
+-------------------------+--------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+
| Field                   | Type         | Collation         | Null | Key | Default |
+-------------------------+--------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+
| rks                     | varchar(20)  | latin1_bin        | YES  | PRI | NULL    |
+-------------------------+--------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+

After alter table:
+-------------------------+--------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+
| Field                   | Type         | Collation         | Null | Key | Default |
+-------------------------+--------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+
| rks                     | varchar(40)  | latin1_bin        | NO   | PRI |         |
+-------------------------+--------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+
```

See that NULL is erased, if the field was integer type, this would change to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd ignore the Default being set to NULL in a column with a primary key. It does not mean that this is the value that it defaults to. When a column is part of a primary key it cannot be NULL, the "Null" column in show tables is what determines the behavior.

```
mysql> drop table FileTable;create table FileTable( rks varchar(20) default NULL collate latin1_bin, pk int auto_increment, primary key(pk, rks));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show columns from FileTable;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| rks   | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI |         |                |
| pk    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

In the above table I added a composite key and show columns has a NULL as default in the pk column. This is obviously nonsense because it's also auto_increment.

I also found some more details here

[Can a primary key default be NULL? Why is it described as such?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850570/can-a-primary-key-default-be-null-why-is-it-described-as-such)

Comment: Thanks for the answer